# Application to automatically search and scrape a website

Tags: database-connection

What application should I use that automatically access a website to gather information?

Basically I have a database that completes calculations for me; however I have to manually gather the parameters from a website and input these into my database.

What I would like is have an application that will do the following:

1. I enter name of a product,
2. The application accesses the website, using the site's search function to locate information on the product,
3. The application downloads certain information on that product,
4. It performs calculations on that information, then
5. Displays the results of those calculations to me

This is a little out of my depth but I’m willing to learn no matter how complicated the software.

Comment: This site is about software development, not necessarily selecting/using software. You might be better off asking this on [su].

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking for a database. You need to write an application that will go and get data from web pages and then stuff these into a database.
i.e. you need to build a "crawler" or "scraper", then drop the results into some database such as MySQL.

Comment: Hi Chris

What software should I consider for building a "crawler/scraper" application?